# Strech the background image on the entire flex-item

Tags: css, flexbox, background

I've been working on this form project using Flexbox and I am completely stuck on how to stretch the background image of the flex-item("#right") so that there is no space around the image( I figure that's the default color of the body's background) but I can't seem to achieve that...
As you can  in this image, the white space doesn't disappear even though I used: cover.

Here is my css for this flex-item:

```
#right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url("newimg.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    color: orangered;
```

I would be really grateful to get some help, been stuck on this for a while trying to figure it out myself and not coming here straight away but I really can't tell. I am still learning flexbox and it might be a beginner's mistake...

[Flexbox-background image stretch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojcll.jpg)

Comment: I think it is default body margin so add css for this `body{margin: 0}` and check it

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right!